# API returns flags options for election comments while flagging them isn't possible

Tags: bug, api-v2.2, comments, flags, elections

When trying to retrieve the flag options on a comment, e.g. on [the currently active one on Skeptics.SE](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/election) (but it works for any election):

https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/comment-flag-options#id=222163&filter=default&site=skeptics

you'll get (if you're authenticated) the familiar comment flag options:

[image]

but it's not possible to flag them (neither via the API nor via the site).